How to render the display for the chip8 implementation
hi guy's so i've been working on this chip8 emulator and I'm half done with finishing the project. the issue i'm having is how to render the display via sdl. i know how to create a window and display it but i don't know how to render the screen using chip8->display[][] array. here is my code for the written chip8 implementation
chip8.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>


#include "chip8.h"

const uint8_t font[80] = {
0xF0, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xF0, // 0
0x20, 0x60, 0x20, 0x20, 0x70, // 1
0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, // 2
0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, // 3
0x90, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x10, 0x10, // 4
0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, // 5
0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, // 6
0xF0, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x40, // 7
0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, // 8
0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, // 9
0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x90, 0x90, // A
0xE0, 0x90, 0xE0, 0x90, 0xE0, // B
0xF0, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0xF0, // C
0xE0, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xE0, // D
0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, // E
0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x80, 0x80  // F
};


void render_display() {
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *surface = NULL;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not be initalized! SDL_ERROR: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
    }
    else {    
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("CHIP8" , 0, 0, 100, 100, 0);
        if(window == NULL) {
            printf("Window could not be created: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        }
        else {
            surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
            SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            SDL_Event e;
            bool quit = false;
            while( quit == false ) {
                while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) ) {
                    if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                        quit = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Init chip8 data
void chip8_init(chip8_t *chip8) {    
    FILE *rom = fopen(chip8->rom,"rb"); // load the rom
    uint16_t entry_point = 0x200;

    if(!rom) {
        fprintf(stdout,"Error Openning rom or rom file not exists %s\n",chip8->rom);
    }

    fseek(rom,0,SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(rom);
    rewind(rom);

    if(fread(&chip8->ram[entry_point],fsize,1,rom) != 0) {
        fprintf(stdout,"rom loaded\n");
    }
    fclose(rom);
    
    memcpy(&chip8->ram[0x50],font,0x09F-0x050); //load the fontset   
}

// Emulate the chip8 cycle
void emulate_cycle(chip8_t *chip8) {    
    chip8->inst.opcode = chip8->ram[chip8->PC] << 8 | chip8->ram[chip8->PC+1]; // shift the program counter value by 8bits and OR operation to combine other value

    chip8->PC = chip8->PC+ 2; 

    chip8->inst.X = (chip8->inst.opcode >> 8) & 0x000F; 
    chip8->inst.Y = (chip8->inst.opcode >> 4) & 0x000F;
    chip8->inst.N = (chip8->inst.opcode & 0x000F);
    chip8->inst.NN = (chip8->inst.opcode & 0x00FF); 
    chip8->inst.NNN = (chip8->inst.opcode & 0x0FFF);

    switch(chip8->inst.opcode & 0xF000) {
        default:
            break;
        case 0x0000:
            switch(chip8->inst.opcode & 0x00FF) {
                case 0xEE:
                    chip8->PC = *(chip8->stack_ptr - 1);
                    break;
                case 0xE0:
                    memset(chip8->display,false,sizeof chip8->display);
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case 0x1000:
            chip8->PC = chip8->inst.NNN;
            break;
        case 0x2000:
            *(++chip8->stack_ptr) = chip8->PC;
            chip8->PC = chip8->inst.NNN;
        case 0x3000:
            if(chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] == chip8->inst.NN) {
                chip8->PC += 2;
            }
            break;
        case 0x4000:
            if(chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] != chip8->inst.NN) {
                chip8->PC += 2;
            }
            break;
        case 0x5000:
            if(chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] == chip8->inst.Y) {
                chip8->PC += 2;
            }
            break;
        case 0x6000:
            chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = chip8->inst.NN;
            break;
        case 0x7000:
            chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] += chip8->inst.NN;
            break;
        case 0x8000:
            switch(chip8->inst.opcode & 0x000F) {
                case 0:
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = (chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] | chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = (chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] & chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = (chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] ^ chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y]);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    chip8->carry_flag = (uint16_t)((chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] + chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y])> 255);
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = (chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] + chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y]) & 0x00FF;
                    chip8->V[0xF] = chip8->carry_flag;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    chip8->carry_flag = (uint16_t)(chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] > chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y]);
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] -= chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y];
                    chip8->V[0xF] = chip8->carry_flag;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    chip8->V[0xF] = chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] & 1;
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] >>= 1;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y] - chip8->V[chip8->inst.X];
                    chip8->carry_flag = (uint16_t) ( chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y] >= chip8->V[chip8->inst.X]);
                    chip8->V[0xF] = chip8->carry_flag;
                    break;
                case 0xE:
                    chip8->V[0xF] = chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] >> 7;
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] <<= 1;
                    break;    
            }
            break;
        case 0x9000:
            if(chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] != chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y]) {
                chip8->PC +=  2;
            }
            break;
        case 0xA000:
            chip8->I = chip8->inst.NNN;
            break;
        case 0xB000:
            chip8->PC = chip8->inst.NNN + chip8->V[0x0];
            break;
        case 0xC000:
            chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = (rand() % 255 + 0)  & chip8->inst.NN;
            break;
        case 0xD000:
            uint8_t x = chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] % 64;
            uint8_t y = chip8->V[chip8->inst.Y] % 32;
            uint8_t height = chip8->inst.N;
            uint8_t pixel;

            chip8->V[0xF] = 0;

            for(int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
                pixel = chip8->ram[chip8->I + row]; 

                for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                    if((pixel & (0x80 >> col)) != 0 ) {
                        int index = (x + col) + ((y + row) * 64);

                        if(chip8->display[x + col ][y + row] == 1) {
                            chip8->V[0xF] = 1;  
                        }

                        chip8->display[x+col][y+row] ^= 1;
                    }
                }    
            }
            break;
        case 0xE000:
            if(chip8->inst.NN == 0x9E) {
                if(chip8->keypad[chip8->V[chip8->inst.X]]) {
                    chip8->PC += 2;
                }
            }
            else if(chip8->inst.NN == 0xA1){
                if(!chip8->keypad[chip8->V[chip8->inst.X]]) {
                    chip8->PC += 2;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 0xF000:
            static bool key_pressed = false;
            switch(chip8->inst.NN){
                case 0x07:
                    chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = chip8->dt;
                    break;
                case 0x0A:
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof chip8->keypad; i++) {
                        if(chip8->keypad[i]) {
                            key_pressed = true;
                            chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!key_pressed) {
                        chip8->PC -= 2;
                    }
                    break;
                case 0x15:
                    chip8->dt  = chip8->V[chip8->inst.X];
                    break;
                case 0x18:
                    chip8->st = chip8->V[chip8->inst.X];
                    break;
                case 0x1E:
                    chip8->I += chip8->V[chip8->inst.X];
                    break;
                case 0x29:
                    chip8->I += chip8->V[chip8->inst.X] * 5;
                    break;
                case 0x33:
                    uint16_t bcd_value = chip8->V[chip8->inst.X];
                    uint16_t bcd = 0;
                    int shift = 0;

                    while(bcd_value > 0) {
                        bcd |= (bcd_value % 10) << (shift++ << 2);
                        bcd /= 10;
                    }    

                    chip8->ram[chip8->I + 2] = bcd % 10;
                    bcd /= 10;
                    chip8->ram[chip8->I + 1] = bcd % 10;
            bcd /= 10;
            chip8->ram[chip8->I] = bcd;

            break;
        case 0x55:
            for(uint8_t i = 0; i <= chip8->inst.X; i++) {
                chip8->ram[chip8->I++] = chip8->V[i];
            }

            break;

        case 0x65:
            for(uint8_t i = 0; i <= chip8->inst.X; i++) {
                chip8->V[i] = chip8->ram[chip8->I++];
            }

            break;    
        }
    }
}

and this is my main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "chip8.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
    chip8_t chip8 = {0};
    chip8.rom = argv[1];
    chip8_init(&chip8);        

    render_display();
    for(int i = 0x50; i<= 0x09F;i++) {
        printf("%x\n",chip8.ram[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

and this is chip8.h
#ifndef CHIP8
#define CHIP8

typedef struct {
    uint16_t opcode;
    uint8_t X;
    uint8_t Y;
    uint8_t N;
    uint8_t NN;
    uint8_t NNN;
} instruction_t;    

typedef struct {
    uint8_t ram[4096];
    uint16_t stack[16];
    uint16_t *stack_ptr;
    bool display[64][32];
    uint8_t V[16];
    uint16_t PC;
    uint16_t I;
    uint16_t registers[16];
    uint16_t keypad[16];
    const char *rom;
    unsigned char dt;
    unsigned char st;
    uint16_t carry_flag;
    instruction_t inst;
} chip8_t;    

void emulate_cycle(chip8_t *chip8);
void chip8_init(chip8_t *chip8);
void render_display();

#endif


What does (or does not) work about this code? What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

this is  a chip8 implementation written in C. the chip8 emulation cycle is finished i want to do is render the display via sdl using the display property on chip8->display array
